# Genymotion does not show window, fails with error 1003

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit

I can't figure out why the Genymotion window doesn't show up on my Kali Linux.  When I start the same image using VirtualBox it starts up but when I start using Genymotion, the emulator window shows up without anything and then suddenly disappears.  Could someone please help me?

```
$ sudo /opt/genymotion/genymotion
Logging activities to file: /root/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Logging activities to file: /root/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Logging activities to file: /root/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Google Nexus 7 2013 - 4.3 - API 18 - 1200x1920/genymotion-player.log
OpenGL connected to 192.168.56.101:25000
Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
Unknown TCPCLI command 1003
```

Contents of the log file are as follows:

```
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  **** 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 2.4.0 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("/opt/genymotion/genymotion") 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting: "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/debian/x64/" 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] done 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel" 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7ffafbff" 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage" 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [getGenymotionLastVersion] New version ( "2.4.0" ) available here: "http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.4.0/genymotion-2.4.0_x64_debian.bin" 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] Genymotion is up to date 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 7918 
Mar 13 23:33:43 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "dhcpservers") returns 0 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Error] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "create") returns 1 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Error] Output command: "0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp" 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Error] failed to create host only interface 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Error] "Fail to load vboxmanage plugin from /opt/genymotion/plugins/" 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Error] VM Engine failed to load 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to find VM Engine. Plugin loading aborted. 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LogCollector] VM engine not available 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LogCollector] Creating temporary folder: "/tmp/genymotion-logs-tmp" 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LogCollector] Copying file "/home/trance/.config/VirtualBox/VBoxSVC.log" to "/tmp/genymotion-logs-tmp/general-VBoxSVC.log" 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "/opt/genymotion/tools/glewinfo" with args () 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "lsmod" with args () 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "lspci" with args () 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "ip" with args ("rule") 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "ip" with args ("route") 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "free" with args () 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "ps" with args ("afx") 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "df" with args ("-kh") 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "dmesg" with args () 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Warning] [LogCollector] Running "cat" with args ("/proc/cpuinfo") 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LogCollector] Copying file "/home/trance/.Genymobile/genymotion.log" to "/tmp/genymotion-logs-tmp/general-genymotion.log" 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [archiveDirectory] Archive created under "/home/trance/genymotion-log.zip" 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LogCollector] Removing temporary folder: "/tmp/genymotion-logs-tmp" 
Mar 13 23:33:44 [Genymotion] [Debug] Result for "Generating log archive..." true 
Mar 13 23:33:46 [Genymotion] [Error] **** STOPPING GENYMOTION WITH ERROR **** 
Mar 13 23:33:46 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STOPPING GENYMOTION  ****
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your virtualbox application is working properly by running it via command terminal.

```
virtualbox
```

For this application to work, you must have the virtualbox kernel module set up. If you did not have it set up during install, it will tell you via terminal and instruct you on how to set it up.

```
Example: "Please recompile the kernel module and install it by: sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Before you run the setup for the virtualbox drive, you will need to have the 3.10.18 linux kernel installed, as the setup will fail telling you the kernel cannot be found without it. You can learn how to install this kernel via http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/install-linux-kernel-3-10-18-ubuntu-mint/

After you have installed the kernel and restarted, you may run the vboxdrv setup command shown earlier and test if virtualbox works via command line. If virtualbox works properly, you may run genymotion successfully with it being able to load the virtual drives.

Answer (score 0):

Networking has to be enabled on VirtualBox.

*Open VirtualBox, then go to:*

```
File>Preferences>Networking
```

I didn't have time to fool around, so I just clicked the plus for NAT-networking and for Host-Only networking. After that I ran ./genymotion again and the screen popped up. Don't know what fixed it, but it's fixed, and that's all I did, cause the [instructions](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide) say that networking had to be enabled, but Ubuntu never gave that option during install.